# Sending file to VirusTotal with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, virus-scanning

I am a student trying out another mini project where the user can upload a CSV file to the web server. But before I can create another program to execute the file, I would like to send the file to virustotal to have it check for virus.

I tried but I got an error: "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.FileInfo'"

Here is my codes:

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using VirusTotalNET;

namespace Testing_1.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string filename = file.FileName;
        VirusTotal vtObj = new VirusTotal("%API KEY%");
        string resID = vtObj.ScanFile(file.FileName);
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/CSV/" + file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        ViewBag.Path = path;
        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

*I got the error at this line: string resID = vtObj.ScanFile(file.FileName);*

**Index**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =   "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input type="file" name="File" id="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

**Upload**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

<h2>Uploaded: @ViewBag.Path</h2>
```

Please help me Thank you

Comment: You need to save the file first, then create a `FileInfo` object (`FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathToSavedFile);` and then pass `fileInfo` to the `ScanFile()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct you are using this library from your code [VirusTotal.NET](https://github.com/Genbox/VirusTotal.NET)

Then, if you look at their documentation, you could notice that the ScanFile method requires an object of type FileInfo and returns an object of type ScanResults. So strings are not included in any way here.

As such you need to save your file somewhere in your file system and then create a FileInfo object

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string filename = Server.MapPath("~/CSV/" + file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(filename);
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
    VirusTotal vtObj = new VirusTotal("%API KEY%");
    ScanResults result = vtObj.ScanFile(fi);
    .. ??? what to do if this is a virus ????
    ViewBag.Path = filename;
    return View();
}
```

Now this could pose a problem with any antivirus program running on your server. Saving it before running the VirusTotal scan could trigger an action by your installed antivirus. So perhaps you should have a temporary folder excluded by your antivirus configuration, save the file there and then (after a successful scan) move the file to the correct destination folder (or in case of problems delete the file from the temporary folder).

Comment: I did not think that far yet. I am doing this project for a security module. I still do not know how to move a saved file to another folder. But I have another error with implementing virustotal.

Comment: I checked around the office: It's not recommended to download the file before you have scanned it. There are ways to do that with V2 of the API.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to view the document and api of [virus total](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/) to implement the uploading feature in your mini project.

Comment: Yes, I did that way before i started. As .NET is a third party for virustotal

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer above is not a good idea (downloading the file to scan it) due to security concerns. Don't use ScanResult. It just gives you a Queued response code that is useless for real-time file uploads to your server. V2.0 of TotalVirus (available via NuGet Package Manager) allows you to pass in the byte[] contents to the GetFileReportAsync method, which provides quick feedback on whether it is infected:

```
    VirusTotal virusTotal = new VirusTotal("Your API Key Here");
    
    FileReport fileReport = await virusTotal.GetFileReportAsync(file.Content);
    
    while (fileReport.ResponseCode == FileReportResponseCode.Queued)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    
    if (fileReport.Positives != 0)
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("File", "File contains potential viruses. Cannot continue with this file.");
       return View(model);
    }
```

You will need to get an API key from TotalVirus. The default key is free but only allows 4 uploads per minute. Good enough for now but you'll definitely need to purchase a professional key for high-traffic web pages.
NOTE 1: I am not including any information about HOW I got the byte[] contents uploaded. That is another matter. I refer you [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for that discussion. NOTE2: I found a halfway decent github project [here](https://github.com/Genbox/VirusTotalNet) that helped me write the code above. NOTE3: I am not quite sure how to detect when you've exceeded the limits of the free API key. It's a ResponseCode, no doubt. You'll figure it out.